# VB net Listbox Colour Error

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an ownerdraw list box and am trying to use the below to change colour.

This works fine except when I exit the application I get an error

InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index on line         e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.Items(e.Index)), e.Font, b, e.Bounds)

How can I stop this please.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DrawItem
    e.DrawBackground()
    If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, e.Bounds)
    End If

    Using b As New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.Items(e.Index)), e.Font, b, e.Bounds)
    End Using
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
End Sub
```

Comment: `If e.Index < 0 Then Exit Sub` ?

Comment: Thanks I came to same idea a few mins ago, just having a brain dead moment